# include / require в PHP выводит содержимое на экран, а не внутрь кода

Tags: php, mysql

Создал подключение к базе данных MySQL. Сделал отдельный файл "conf.php" с данными:

```
$dblocation = "..."; // Имя сервера
$dbuser = "...";          // Имя пользователя
$dbpasswd = "...";            // Пароль
$dbname = "...";    //база данных
```

В основном файле в коде пишу

```
include "conf.php";
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation,$dbuser,$dbpasswd);
if (!$dbcnx) // Если дескриптор равен 0 соединение не установлено
{
echo("<P>В настоящий момент сервер базы данных не доступен, поэтому 
       корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</P>");
exit();
}
...
```

Файл читается, но почему-то данные из него выводятся на экран. Не понимаю в чем причина. (если прописать переменные в основном файле, то все работает)

Comment: в первом файле в начале и конце есть `<?php` ... `?>`?

Comment: Да, разумеется.

Comment: Файл считывается, но выводится, как будто бы через echo

Comment: Покажите первый файл со всеми строками (данные естественно нужно скрыть)

Comment: Поищите по всему проекту строку "conf.php", нет ли где-нибудь странных конструкций с его участием? Может чтение в переменную?

Comment: tutankhamun, добавил в описании. Дальше точно писать нет смысла. Выводятся данные из файла conf.php и ошибка подключения к базе (что понятно, переменные-то не заданы)

Comment: Nikola Tesla, неправильно вас понял в первый раз))) Думал про другой файл. Спасибо! Да. дело в <?php ... ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В подключаемом файле `conf.php` необходимо указывать в начале `<?php`

Comment: В конце ?> необязательно, даже вредно - если после него будет перевод строки, то это спровоцирует вывод данных.  И даже нарушает PSR-2 "The closing ?> tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP."

Comment: Дурацкий вопрос принес много знаний) Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Мелкий, спасибо за комментарий, изменил ответ.